# How to re-ask for input in try catch statement

Tags: c#

```
string l = Console.ReadLine();

try
{
    int.Parse(l);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
}
```

As you can see, I have asked for input, but if the user enters a non-integral answer such as the letter "f", the catch statement catches it, but then throws the exception again afterwards, because the variable "l" still equals "f". Help?

Comment: Seems you should learn what a loop is before you start using try catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of catching exceptions. It returns whether the parse was successful, so you can check it in a loop until the input is valid e.g.

```
int i;
bool valid = false;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an int: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    valid = int.TryParse(input, out i);
} while(! valid);

//use i
```

Comment: There's no need to declare an additional `bool` field for this if you embed the `TryCatch` in the condition of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use TryParse with a while loop (since your condition can fail an infinite number of times).

```
string l = Console.ReadLine();

int line = 0;

while(!int.TryParse(l, out line))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
    l = Console.ReadLine();
}

// line contains a valid number here.
```

Answer (score 2):

don't do it that way.  Use TryParse instead

```
        string l = Console.ReadLine();

        int i;

        while(int.TryParse(l, out i) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
            l = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: @SpikeX I personally think that `!int.TryParse(l, out i)` looks too similar to `int.TryParse(l, out i)`  It improves readability for me

Comment: @ChaosPandion Your IDE should be responsible for relaying type information, not your code.

Comment: @SpikeX - I was being snarky.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Oh, sorry, you forgot to use `<snark></snark>` tags, so I couldn't tell. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can handle this. One way it to wrap all of this in a loop allowing a given number of retries or just a while loop that keeps going until the user enters valid input. Another is to put it all in a method and call it recursively from the catch block. I think the best solution is neither, instead I would use `Int.TryParse` and I would have that inside a while loop like;

```
 while (!Int32.TryParse(input, out line))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
      input = Console.ReadLine();
 }
```